# Unable to find newly installed svn version on CentOS

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I had sve version 1.7 installed on CentOS and now I installed svn 1.11 using following command -

```
sudo yum localinstall CollabNetSubversion-client-1.11.1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

but after hitting `svn --version`, it still showing `1.7` version. Please guide me to what else I need to do to use latest version 1.11 of svn.

This might be trivial question but I haven't worked on linux environment more. Please help.

Comment: What's your `PATH` and what's the output from `type -all svn`? You probably have the old version in `/usr/local/bin` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can exec command

```
rpm -ql CollabNetSubversion-client-1.11.1-1.x86_64
```

and from the list get the location of new `svn`. Then you can add the directory where this is installed on the first place in PATH:

```
export PATH=/here/is/the/location:$PATH
```

(and add this to `~/.bashrc` also)